# Drop duplicates horizontal in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Sorry I cant figure out how to drop duplicate values but horizontal. The function `drop_duplicate` does not have a index parameter.

So i have one dataframe

| contact | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 | phone4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |  | 1234 |  |
| 2 |  | 12345 |  | 12345 |

And I want to have the following dataframe:

| contact | phone1 | phone2 | phone3 | phone4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | 12345 |  |  |

Comment: `df.T.drop_duplicates().T.reindex_like(df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Can use stack and reindex

```
df.stack().drop_duplicates().unstack().reindex(columns=df.columns).fillna('')



  contact  phone1   phone2 phone3 phone4
0      1.0  1234.0                       
1      2.0          12345.0
```

Option2:To replace duplicates row wise, please try first NaN with 0 (a value that does not exist in the df). Mask the duplicates and fill them with '', then replace 0 with NaN to restore the df

```
df.fillna(0).mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1)).fillna('').replace(0,np.nan)

  contact  phone1   phone2   phone3 phone4
0        1  1234.0      NaN              
1        2     NaN  12345.0
```

Option 3:

To achieve your outcome as put. We can  just:

```
df.mask(df.apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(), axis=1)).fillna('') 



contact  phone1   phone2 phone3 phone4
0      1.0  1234.0                       
1      2.0          12345.0
```

Comment: hi thanks! I am using your Option 3. But my dataframe has many more columns. Is there a way to only drop duplicates from columns 'phone1', 'phone2', 'phone3' 'phone4'.